# Undefined method for nil:NilClass on `current_user`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in my Rails application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try to get user restaurants and the users don't have any restaurants, I am getting the following error:

> Undefined method `restaurants' for nil:NilClass

I am checking the method is nil with following code but it doesn't work:

```
if !current_user.restaurants.nil?
  @restaurants = current_user.restaurants.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
end
```

How can I check if a user's restaurants is `nil`?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is the missing method really named `xx`? Just asking because there is no call of a method named `xx` in your example.

Comment: Maybe the error is that `current_user` is `nil` and you get that error when calling `restaurants` on it.

Comment: I am getting following errors ,I edited the question : undefined method `restaurants' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Do u use devise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `current_user`:

> "undefined method `restaurants' for nil:NilClass"

`current_user` is `nil`, so it can't respond to `restaurants`. You need to set up `current_user` first.

Comment: yes you are right. I am new in RoR and error code some weird for me. I am waiting current_user is nill as first error.